# JSON from Rails to Angularjs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, heroku

I’m trying to use Angularjs to get JSON from a Rails test app that I put on Heroku. Below you will find my Angular and Rails code.

This is the error that I get in my Firebug console.
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://desolate-earth-2852.herokuapp.com/declarations.json"

**Is there a reason this is not working?**

### Angularjs code

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://desolate-earth-2852.herokuapp.com/declarations.json')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.todos = res.data;        
        });
});
```

### Rails code

```
  def index
    @declarations = Declaration.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @declarations }
    end
  end
```

### Here are the routes

```
Test::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'welcome#index'
  get "welcome/index"
  resources :declarations
end
```

Comment: Do You have routes defined like this: `resources :declarations` ?

Comment: yes, post your routes.rb code

Comment: I have added the routes. I had resources :declarations already.

Comment: that's odd you get a 404. Are you running the angular code also from the same herokuapp? Could you specify the url where the angular code runs?

Comment: @ Manuel van Rijn. I'm running the Angular code locally on my desktop

Answer (score 5):

It might be because of Rails JS minification. Ryan Bates talks about this in his [Railscast about integrating AngularJS](http://railscasts.com/episodes/405-angularjs?view=asciicast). I notice that you have nothing mentioning that you were accounting for the minification in your config files, and if you aren't, then that means that all of your Dependency Injection in your Angular code needs to be put into and array, like this:

```
App.controller('TodoCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://desolate-earth-2852.herokuapp.com/declarations.json')
    .then(function(res){
       $scope.todos = res.data;        
    });
}]);
```

Instead of this:

```
App.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://desolate-earth-2852.herokuapp.com/declarations.json')
   .then(function(res){
      $scope.todos = res.data;        
   });
});
```

This tells AngularJS what the dependencies are so that if the names do change (during minification) it won’t matter. You have to do this for every function that accepts services, for example the one you have here for creating the app's controller.